# How to sort alphanumeric list of Django model objects

Tags: python, django, sorting

I am trying to port the answer to the question posed in [How to sort alpha numeric set in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2669059/how-to-sort-alpha-numeric-set-in-python) to Django. I have a list of Django model instances returned by a query and I can't work out how to use lambda to construct an elegant (or otherwise!) sort function.

If my model contains a 'name' attribute - e.g.

```
result = Take.objects.all()
for i in result:
   print i.name
```

How can I sort the resulting list of objects by the name attribute and apply a number of tests?

i.e. my name value could be '1A','1','A1','001A' etc

e.g.
 to give this ordering (based on name)

```
1A
2A
10A
A1
A2
A10
A11
B2
B4
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `operator.attrgetter` to sort your objects by the value of an attribute:

```
import operator

class Foo:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

l = [Foo('AA'), Foo('a'), Foo('AB')]
l.sort(key=operator.attrgetter('name'))
print [o.name for o in l]
['AA', 'AB', 'a']
```

Here is another answer I provided [which defines a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5254021/python-human-sort-of-numbers-with-alpha-numeric-but-in-pyqt-and-a-lt-opera/5254534#5254534) to perform alpha-numeric sort in "human" order.  Merging the `_human_key` function into the example above, you could do:

```
l.sort(key=lambda x: _human_key(x.name))
print [o.name for o in l]
['a', 'AA', 'AB']
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue where I tried to order a Queryset in a similar manner
although I use a custom function to accomplish the order

1AreaDesk.
2-1-1Desk.
10AreaDesk.
AreaDesk.
Desk1

I realized that using the Lower function from Django produced the same result
    from django.db.models.functions import Lower

eg

```
Model.objects.filter(**filter_query).order_by(Lower("attribute_name")
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
result = Take.objects.order_by('name')
for x in result:
    print x
```

However, the example ordering you mention is not a normal alphanumeric (lexicographic) ordering as I know it.  Instead, it would be:

```
10A
1A
2A
A1
A10
A11
A2
B2
B4
```

If you really want the ordering you specify, you'd have to get more creative.

Comment: I'd mark this down if I had reputation. Yes, I really want the order I specified...

Comment: Your answer suggests very easy solution to completely another problem.