# python QstandardItemModel Natural sort

Tags: python, pyqt, natural-sort, pyside2

I'm looking for QstandardItemModel Natural Sort Method. I'm reading some relevant question and try to my code. But It didn't work

My tool accept Some File list by Drag and Drop. I want to sort my Model data by Natural sort. and put it to listview.

So Here is my code:

```
class VideolistView (QtWidgets.QListView):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(VideolistView, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.setObjectName("VideolistView")
        self.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(8, 30, 250, 301))
        self.Model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel(self)

    def dragEnterEvent(self, event):
        if event.mimeData().hasUrls:
            event.accept()
        else:
            event.ignore()

    def dragMoveEvent(self, event):
        if event.mimeData().hasUrls:
            event.accept()
        else:
            event.ignore()

    def dropEvent(self, event):
        if event.mimeData().hasUrls:
            event.setDropAction(QtCore.Qt.CopyAction)
            event.accept()

            for url in event.mimeData().urls():
                dropitem = str(url.toLocalFile())
                Fname = os.path.split(dropitem)
                if not self.Model.findItems(Fname[1]):
                    listitem = QtGui.QStandardItem(Fname[1])
                    self.Model.appendRow(listitem)
            self.Model.sort(0)
            self.setModel(self.Model)
        else:
            event.ignore()
```

Some my attemp announce.

```
import re

def _human_key(key):
    parts = re.split('(\d*\.\d+|\d+)', key)
    return tuple((e.swapcase() if i % 2 == 0 else float(e))
            for i, e in enumerate(parts))
   ......

    listitems=[]
         for url in event.mimeData().urls():
             dropitem = str(url.toLocalFile())
             Fname = os.path.split(dropitem)
             listitem = QtGui.QStandardItem(Fname[1])
             listitems.appent(listitem)
    listitems.sort(key=_human_key)
```

Pycharm debug Error listitems.sort(key=_human_key) and I tried reimplement of QstandardItemModel class

```
import re

def _human_key(key):
    parts = re.split('(\d*\.\d+|\d+)', key)
    return tuple((e.swapcase() if i % 2 == 0 else float(e))
            for i, e in enumerate(parts))
   ......

Class NaturalSortModel (QtGui.QstandardItemModel)
    def __lt__(self, other):
        column = self.treeWidget().sortColumn()
        k1 = self.text(column)
        k2 = other.text(column)
        return _human_key(k1) < _human_key(k2)
               .......
Class VideolistView (QtWidgets.QListView)
    def __init__(self, parent):
       self.Model = self.NaturalSortModel(self)

               ........
            self.Model.appendRow(listitem)
        self.Model.sort(0)
        self.setModel(self.Model)
                ........
```

above Two code Error. How I do Natural Sort with QstandardItemModel?

link : [Python - Human sort of numbers with alpha numeric, but in pyQt and a __lt__ operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5254021/python-human-sort-of-numbers-with-alpha-numeric-but-in-pyqt-and-a-lt-oper)

With @eyllanesc Answer, First Solution with QSortFilterProxyModel Work well.
It sort data by Natural order.

But @eyllanesc second advice(Qstandarditem inherit) is not work for me. It sort Alphabetically just like original source.
@eyllanesc Thank you a lot!!!

Comment: What does it mean: But it did not work?

Comment: Google Search teach to me about List Nature Sort. So I make list with listitem. Listitems.append(listitem) and Listitems.sort(key=nature_sort). but error occured.

Comment: I do not understand, that is the ordering of lists in python, and it is not only for natural ordering but for any ordering criteria.

Comment: the lists and QStandarItemModel are very different things, I tried although it is not the best but it works, it orders them in a natural way.

Comment: Is it work? My pycharm debug and error. I tried def __lt__(self, other):
    return naturalkey(self.value, float) < naturalkey(other.value, float) implemet of QStandardItemModel class but Fail...

Comment: I do not talk about your comment, but about the code you show in your question.

Comment: Why do you get complicated if QStandarItemModel already uses that sort order when you use your_model.sort(your_column)?

Comment: yes. QstandardItemModel sort desending But It's not Natural Order. I want to Sort QstandardItemModel by Natural order.

Comment: Try my answer, and if it works mark it as correct please.

Comment: @abrakad. The `__lt__` is supposed to be used in a sub-class of `QStandardItem`, not a model. PS: there are some other errors in your code - you need to use `event.mimeData().hasUrls()` (note the `()` at the end).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to establish a particular criterion of order you must do it through a model that inherits from `QSortFilterProxyModel` and implement the method `lessThan` as I show below:

```
class NaturalSortFilterProxyModel(QtCore.QSortFilterProxyModel):
    @staticmethod
    def _human_key(key):
        parts = re.split('(\d*\.\d+|\d+)', key)
        return tuple((e.swapcase() if i % 2 == 0 else float(e)) for i, e in enumerate(parts))

    def lessThan(self, left, right):
        leftData = self.sourceModel().data(left)
        rightData = self.sourceModel().data(right)
        return self._human_key(leftData) < self._human_key(rightData)

class VideolistView (QtWidgets.QListView):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(VideolistView, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.setObjectName("VideolistView")
        self.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(8, 30, 250, 301))
        model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel(self)
        proxyModel = NaturalSortFilterProxyModel()
        proxyModel.setSourceModel(model)
        proxyModel.sort(0, QtCore.Qt.AscendingOrder)
        self.setModel(proxyModel)

    def dragEnterEvent(self, event):
        if event.mimeData().hasUrls():
            event.accept()
        else:
            event.ignore()

    def dragMoveEvent(self, event):
        if event.mimeData().hasUrls():
            event.accept()
        else:
            event.ignore()

    def dropEvent(self, event):
        if event.mimeData().hasUrls():
            event.setDropAction(QtCore.Qt.CopyAction)
            event.accept()

            for url in event.mimeData().urls():
                dropitem = str(url.toLocalFile())
                Fname = os.path.split(dropitem)
                if not self.model().sourceModel().findItems(Fname[1]):
                    listitem = QtGui.QStandardItem(Fname[1])
                    self.model().sourceModel().appendRow(listitem)
        else:
            event.ignore()
```

As [@ekhumuro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/984421/ekhumoro) says, the solution shown in the link refers to creating a class that inherits from `QStandardItem`, as I show below

```
class NaturalStandardItem(QtGui.QStandardItem):
    @staticmethod
    def _human_key(key):
        parts = re.split('(\d*\.\d+|\d+)', key)
        return tuple((e.swapcase() if i % 2 == 0 else float(e)) for i, e in enumerate(parts))
    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self._human_key(self.text()) < self._human_key(other.text())


class VideolistView (QtWidgets.QListView):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(VideolistView, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.setObjectName("VideolistView")
        self.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(8, 30, 250, 301))
        model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel(self)
        self.setModel(model)


    def dragEnterEvent(self, event):
        if event.mimeData().hasUrls():
            event.accept()
        else:
            event.ignore()

    def dragMoveEvent(self, event):
        if event.mimeData().hasUrls():
            event.accept()
        else:
            event.ignore()

    def dropEvent(self, event):
        if event.mimeData().hasUrls():
            event.setDropAction(QtCore.Qt.CopyAction)
            event.accept()

            for url in event.mimeData().urls():
                dropitem = str(url.toLocalFile())
                Fname = os.path.split(dropitem)
                if not self.model().findItems(Fname[1]):
                    listitem = NaturalStandardItem(Fname[1])
                    self.model().appendRow(listitem)
            self.model().sort(0)

        else:
            event.ignore()
```

Comment: Thanky your Help. I didn't test this code yet. But I think It work well. after I test it I note my question.